# Weird Problem! Need to turn steering wheel to crank start the car

Tags: electrical, toyota, ignition, steering, corolla

I have a 1997 Toyota Corolla

It started to have starting problem a few weeks ago.
If I didn't drive my car for 1 or 2, the car won't start. The only way to start the car is to turn the steering wheel from side to side (about 1/4 a circle, from 12 o'clock to 9 and then back), and turn the key at the same time.

I have new engine oil, new oil filter, and oil level is good.
Battery should be ok, only a few years old and I did refill the water.

Steering oil should be ok, I don't know about steering pump condition. It's the original pump, but is it the root of the problem?

I check the coolant, it's ok, too.

Note, I'm not talking about steering column lock. This after I unlock the car and trying to crank the engine.

Comment: Congrats on the weirdest problem that I've heard of in quite a while!

Comment: Sounds like you've got one of those Flintstones cars. Do you find yourself sticking your feet through the floorboard and making a running motion? In all seriousness, the fact that you "need to turn the steering wheel" must be causing parts of a broken connection in the ignition switch to temporarily come back into contact with each other. If it doesn't crank, it's an electrical problem, and the only explanation is that the key switch has a disconnect.

Comment: The problem is that it's very difficult to replicate the problem.
I have to left my car for at lease 2 day for the problem to appear. And after the engine is warm up, it can start with no problem.
I'm replacing the starter, and see if the problem is fix or not.

Comment: I agree with @LynnCrumbling, this smacks of a failing ignition switch (IS). I had trouble with the IS in my '97 Blazer, and equally-unusual solutions seemed to get it started for about a month or two: taking the key off the key ring (i.e. changing the weight in the ballast), using the spare key, wriggling the key slightly before cranking, etc. ..I eventually replaced the IS myself, but it wasn't fun. However it saved me about $3-400 I think.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, now you need to rewrite your comment as an answer!

Comment: @YoungLin   Have resolved the issue?  If so, let us all know.  Interested in knowing what the solution is.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the ignition switch needs to be replaced. Moving the steering wheel from side to side apparently is enough to get it to make enough contact to work. It will fail sooner than later. Have a mechanic look into it. This is a safety issue because the car could very well start turning itself off while driving.